# What's the right spelling of (something I hear, but cannot find, as) "часно слово"?

Tags: значения, правописание

I often hear in Russian an expression that I suppose can be translated as "I swear it", or "I give you my word". I hear something as "часно слово", "час на слово" ?

**What is its right spelling and what does it exactly mean?**

**Remark:** I cannot find it in lingvo, wikipedia, gramota nor by translation, even trying with combinations of possible spelling mistakes (exchanging ч by ш, the о's by a's, итд.)

*Edit:* of course, my ear can just be unmature to hear Russian and detect *all* possible spellings .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually `[моё] честное слово`, which can be translated as `an honest word [of mine]`. Phrase `давать честное слово` is interchangeable with `обещать` (to promise).

There is also a word `клясться`, but this is more close to `to vow`: it is somewhat stronger than making a promise.

Comment: `Честное слово!` is `Upon my word!`, `честное слово` is `the word of honor` - that's a better way to say that in English.

Comment: @YellowSky, sure, I've just provided literate translation.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the question so that it can be useful for more people. Any ideas?

Comment: @c.p. don't worry, I do believe that this question is appropriate here and, therefore, is useful :)